# How do I append parameters to a div tag on button click?

Tags: jquery, click

```
    $(".buttons").on("click", function() { 
           button_value = $(this).attr("value"); 
           button_value.appendTo('#parameter');
     });

    <div> 
        <input class="buttons" type="button" value="*"/>
    </div>
```

For each button click, the value of the button needs to be added to the div.

Answer (score 3):

`button_value` value is not a jQuery object(it will be a string), it is the value of the attribute so it will not have the method `appendTo()`

```
$(".buttons").on("click", function () {
    var button_value = $(this).attr("value");
    $('#parameter').append(button_value);
})
```